# Why sql function return a NULL result?

Tags: sql-server

This is my SQL function

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.limit','FN' ) IS NOT NULL
DROP FUNCTION limit;
Go 
create function dbo.limit(@State_code varchar)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS

BEGIN
DECLARE @ret varchar(max) ;
SELECT @ret = State_Name
FROM aqs_sites
WHERE aqs_sites.State_Code = @State_code and State_Name not like '%guam%'
RETURN @ret ;
END
```

When I call this function in my select syntax

```
go
select distinct [dbo].limit(aqs_sites.State_Code) from aqs_sites
```

I got a NULL result, really have no idea on it. BTW, I use SQL-server 2018.

Comment: *"I use SQL-server 2018"*; that isn't true, SQL Server 2018 doesn't exist.

Comment: Why don't you try getting some more data back to debug what value(s) are being passed into the function: `select aqs_sites.*, [dbo].limit(aqs_sites.State_Code) from aqs_sites`. Also, your return types don't match; the function returns a `varchar` while the signature says it'll return `nvarchar`. Why not make them match?

Comment: I've posted an answer, however I don't understand why you  need the function at all, since both your outer query and function are returning data from the same table. If you want to return guam from result, just add it to the where clause: select distinct state_code from aqs_sites where state_name not like '%guam%'

Comment: @cf_en well I should make my return type matched, but that's not the point to fix result NULL, thanks anyway

Comment: @Daniel N  I created this function because for instance, if I want to select all the state_name except 'guam' for several quries.

Answer (score 1):

Either a row in aqs_sites tables has a null value for State_Name or the value you are passing as @state_code parameter does not return any rows.

looking further at the problem, the null values are returned for the rows where state is guam, which is filtered out within the function

Comment: if @state_code parameter does not return any rows OR all of the entries yeld true to: `State_Name not like '%guam%'` the query would not yeld NULL but an empty table which is why there are questions on how to return NULL when no lines are found in SQL

Comment: @Wolfaloo that's not true. That would only be the case if the table `aqs_sites` contains no rows. A scalar function returns `NULL` is no value is returned, as the return variable is declared and will have a value of `NULL` (provided the return variable doesn't have a default value). [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2ffd16351cdb9c53ba2740b8879ad60f)

Comment: @Daniel N So in this case, should I change @ state_code into @ State_Name and @ ret = State_Name?